# ComponentDidUpdate() causing memory leaks and drainage of battery in IOS

Tags: react-native, memory-leaks, react-native-ios, asyncstorage

I am using componentDidUpdate() method for displaying updated data on screen whenever any functionalities is performed like scanning Qr code and storing data. But after searching on net I found that calling this.setState in componentDidUpdate() creates infinite loop. I tried to remove this problem through including prevState in the above method but I failed. Below is my code for more details. How can I update state coming from Asyncstorage without the help of componentDidUpdate()?

```js
componentDidUpdate() {
    try {
      AsyncStorage.getItem('Data').then((value) => {
        this.setState({
          list: JSON.parse(value)
        })
      })
    } catch (err) {
    }
  }
```

Any help or suggestions would be helpful Thanks.

Comment: you are entering an infinite cycle, because you are not familiar with react life cycle. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html

Answer (score 1):

Updating the state in `componentDidUpdate` will trigger another `componentDidUpdate` call, so you should restrict calling `setState()`. For example:

```js
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {

  // Only update state if list is empty 
  if (prevState.list.length === 0) {

    try {
      AsyncStorage.getItem('Data').then((value) => {
        this.setState({
          list: JSON.parse(value)
        })
      })
    } catch (err) {
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: According to your logic after implementing this I am not able to update the state immediately after asynchronous task. The updated data is only displayed after moving to another screen then coming back to same screen.

Comment: Since I have no clue about your requirements I merely provided an example, you should change the if statement according your needs. You could also update only if a certain prop has changed, or whatever. But generally you should do a check against the previous state or previous props to determine if a new state is required

Comment: Actually I am using Asyncstorage to locally save scanned data from qrcode to my app. So I am using two classes one for saving data locally and another for Scanning qr code so when the qr code is scanned it saves data locally and then I get that data in componentDidUpdate() as shown in my previous code.